# Confidence interval in cochrane armitage test

Tags: cochran-armitage

Hi I am looking to use the cochrane armitage trend test. I have applied to my yearly data set using excelstat software.  How do I get confidence interval in cochrane armitage trend test. Excelstat software does not show confidence interval and p value is less than <0.0001. Could you explain why there is no confidence interval.